# Using afx_msg in Qt with msvc2008 compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, qt, visual-c++, afx

I'm working on a project in Qt with the msvc2008 compiler, as the title says.

The sample code, which I'm trying to work from makes use of afx_maps, and as far as I can tell (I don't really have a clue how afx works), the code below means that when the message WM_PI_RAWDATA_READY is received (I have no idea where or how it's received), the function OnRawDataReady is triggered.

```
//{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CPDImfcDlg)
ON_MESSAGE(WM_PI_RAWDATA_READY, OnRawDataReady )
//}}AFX_MSG_MAP
```

I tried copying the code into my project, and then adding #include  in the header, but it gives me the following error:

```
D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE\afx.h:24: error: C1189: #error :  Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]
```

The fixes I've found elsewhere for this seem to be project settings in visual studio, so I'm not sure how to get around it.

Any ideas on how to fix this, or how to work around the afx_msg stuff?

Many thanks

Comment: And this has anything do to with Qt, because...?

Comment: Because I'm working on the project in Qt, using the microsoft compilers, hence I don't have access to the project settings which are available in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: But code that uses message maps is definitely MFC code and I don't understand why you're bothering with MFC in a Qt project, but perhaps I haven't completely understood the motivation for this. So now my question is, what does a Qt project have to do with MFC message maps.

Comment: @Christian Rau: The sample code for the hardware that I'm using is written in a visual studio project. I wanted to copy the code from the sample project. I don't really understand the whole afx thing, so I'm not sure how I'd adapt it to work. I was expecting it to work fine since I'm using a microsoft compiler, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: It should work if you get around your problem (will post an answer on this) but it just won't really work together with your Qt project, as this code is definitely MFC code (which is another GUI toolkit around the Win32 API). Just integrating this sample into a Qt project is not that good compared to porting it to Qt, from a design point of view, but it should at least work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about just doing what the error message said and `#define`ing the `_AFXDLL` preprocessor symbol. Depending on your build environtment you just need to add it to the complier command line as an argument (`/D_AFXDLL`, if I remember correctly). But when you're working with Qt you probably got a *.pro file anyway and can just add it there (using the `DEFINES` variable). So just add this line to you *.pro file

```
DEFINES += _AFXDLL
```

But just integrating MFC code into a Qt application (which are two completely different GUI and OS abstraction libraries) won't be of too much help, as they both won't work together that good, not to speak of the design issue. Perhaps you can port the application from MFC to Qt.

Comment: I gave the whole DEFINES thing a go, but then I have to remove #include <windows.h>, which creates a whole new slew or errors.

Any idea on what the Qt equivalent of this whole afx_msg thing is? I'll trying tranlating to that...

Comment: Depends on what you know about Qt and MFC (and Win32). The MFC message maps just map windows messages to class methods (actually the `afx_msg` keyword is just defined to nothing, it's for the class wizard). The closest Qt equivalent to Win32 messages are events, but it isn't that easy as just changing some keywords. You will have to redesign the whole application into Qt, which depends on the code and your individual Qt, MFC and Win32 abilities and can get quite complex. It won't just reduce to a few SO questions that need to be answered.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know that much about either of them. The message WM_PI_RAWDATA_READY would be sent by the hardware right? So would it be possible to somehow use QWidget::winEvent() to read this message and then trigger the same event as afx_msg did? The message triggered an 'LRESULT' function, but I don't really know the significance of LRESULT.

Comment: Guess that's a different question, thanks for straightening this out. I'll post a q about winEvent(Filter) later.

Answer (score 0):

It basically says that you have to either use static libraries or DLLs. You cannot mix.

Like you say, this is part of the project settings.